# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, xml

This code is inside a while loop that moves the cursor in a database for each loop. I want that if daysLeftInt is under 6, then the id (R.id.leftColor) should be the color of the variable redColor.

```
            if(daysLeftInt < 6) {
                Context context = this;
                int redColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red);
                TextView rectangleView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.leftColor);
                rectangleView.setBackgroundColor(redColor);

            }
```

I get this error message:

### Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference

This is how my layouts is setup:

Do anyone know how i will get the result that I want?

activity_main.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">


        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

activity_main.xml includes this file called app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.mysubscriptions.alexklug.mysubscriptions.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
<include layout="@layout/content_subscription" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
    android:onClick="openSubscriptionActivity"
    />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml include the layout file content_main.xml which is this file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.mysubscriptions.alexklug.mysubscriptions.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">



<ListView
    android:id="@+id/subscriptionsList"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">
</ListView>
```

Inside the ListView an ArrayAdapter helps displaying the last file called list_item.xml.
The first TextView is the view with the id of leftColor.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/leftColor"
        android:layout_width="3dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.01"
        />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/subscription_image"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_netflix"
        android:padding="10dp"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subscription_name"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:text="First"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"

        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subscription_price"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        tools:text="Second"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".7"
        android:gravity="center"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subscription_days_left"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        tools:text="12"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".7"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/myRectangleView"
        android:layout_width="7dp"
        android:layout_height="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle" />


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You're in an Activity? Do you understand how findViewById works?

Comment: Well, all the other findViewById i have in the same activity is written exactly the same way, however they work. Maybe i dont understand how it works, but do you so you can explain? Is it because it is in a loop that it is going wrong?

Comment: You don't have a loop in the question. But if you did have a loop, you're only setting one layout and finding the exact same view. Whatever layout you set by setContentView does not contain the id you're searching for, therefore it's null

Comment: How do i find the id then?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because "**R.id.leftColor**" doesn't match with the resource in the XML file. In this case, what you can do is hold 'ctrl' and hover the mouse over "**R.id.leftColor**" in java code and click the link it points to which appears after hovering.

1. If it takes it to the resource in the layout XML file, then it's alright, just perform a

> Build->Clean Project
>
> Build->Rebuild Project

2. Else, if it takes to an id in the R.java file, like this

> public static final int leftColor=0x7f0d008c;

then you might have mistakenly renamed the **leftColor** in the layout XML file to something else. Correct that  to whatever you have given in the java code and it should work fine.

Comment: It takes me to the layout XML file if I hold "ctrl" and click on the "R.id.leftColor". The Build->Clean Project and Build->Rebuild Project does nothing. I get the same error message as before.

Comment: @Alex which layout file? I assume you have more than one. Please edit your question to include them

Comment: You can now see the XML files i work with in the description

Comment: Got it, R.id.leftColor is not in the XML file which is there in setContentView()  of that activity. If it is setContentView(R.layout.activity_main), then the "R.id.leftColor" should also be in activity_main.xml.

Answer (score 0):

It's android studios fault, just put in a delay of about 50 milliseconds. Example:

```
 Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                listView.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                listView.getChildAt(1).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                listView.getChildAt(2).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                listView.getChildAt(3).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
        }, 50);
```